# Relations between classes - both inheritance and composition

Tags: c++, inheritance, relationship, composition

I've a game I'm working on, Snake. I've problem with the relationships between classes and I don't really understand why.

I've these three classes:

- Snake - The snake class.
- Food - The food which snake eats
- Object - Has members: width, height, posX and posY

These are the relations:
Snake has unlimited amount of objects from the class Object. Each object is a block for snake. Thereofore in the snake declaration I have:

```
Object **blocks;
```

Then, in the snake constructor I create a array of Objects for blocks. Don't bother about this part, I've tested Snake and made it run with several blocks smoothly. Snake is not the main problem.

Then I try to do inheritance for the Food class, which works as long as I only use a header file and no cpp-file:

```
//Header file for Food
#include "Object.h"
class Food : Object { ............ };
```

So far so good, but!, as soon as I write one single line: #include "Food.h" for food.cpp and try to compile the compiler finds an error in Snake(!?). I've an error saying "Error: "Object" is not the name on a type" for the following line:

```
Object **blocks;
```

Does this mean I can't use a class (Object) for both inheritance and composition?

EDIT: I've to much code and no time to shorten all of it. Here is the code for Object.h (I don't have an object.cpp file cause not needed yet):

```
#ifndef OBJECT_H
#define OBJECT_H

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Snake.h"

class Object {
private:
    int posX;
    int posY;
    int height;
    int width;

public:
    //Get functions
    int getPosX() const { return this->posX; }
    int getPosY() const { return this->posY; }
    int getHeight() const { return this->height; }
    int getWidth() const { return this->width; }

    //Set functions
    void setPosX(int x) { this->posX = x; }
    void setPosY(int y) { this->posY = y; }
    void setHeight(int h) { this->height = h; }
    void setWidth(int w) { this->width = w; }
};

#endif //OBJECT_H
```

Here is the code for Snake.h:

```
#ifndef SNAKE_H
#define SNAKE_H

#include "Object.h"
#include "stdafx.h"

class Snake {
public:
    enum Direction { Left, Right, Up, Down };

private:
    Object **blocks;
    int nrOfBlocks;
    float speed;
    int frontBlock;
    Direction direction;
    sf::Image blockImg;
    sf::Sprite blockSprite;

public:
    Snake();
    ~Snake();

    //Get functions
    int getNrOfBlocks() const { return this->nrOfBlocks; }
    float getSpeed() const { return this->speed; }
    Direction getDirection() const { return this->direction; }
    sf::Image getBlockImg() const { return this->blockImg; }
    sf::Sprite getSprite() const { return this->blockSprite; }

    //Set functions
    void setNrOfBlocks(int nrOfBlocks) { this->nrOfBlocks = nrOfBlocks; }
    void setSpeed(float speed) { this->speed = speed; }
    void setDirection(Direction direction) { this->direction = direction; }
    void setImage(sf::Image image) { this->blockImg = image; }
    void setBlockSprite(sf::Sprite sprite) { this->blockSprite = sprite; }

    void move(int n);
    void newFrontBlock();
    void changeDir(Direction dir);
    sf::Sprite doSprite(int n);
};

#endif //SNAKE_H
```

And here's the code for Food.h:

```
#ifndef FOOD_H
#define FOOD_H

#include "Object.h"
#include "stdafx.h"

class Food : public Object {
private:
    int points;
    int timeExperation;
    sf::Image image;
    sf::Sprite sprite;

public:
    Food();
    int getPoint() const { return this->points; }
    int getTimeExperation() const { return this->timeExperation; }
    void setPoints(int points) { this->points = points; }
    void setTimeExperation(int timeExp) { this->timeExperation =  timeExp; }
};

#endif //FOOD_H
```

I hope it's not to much code. It's mostly just non-important member variables and set-, get-functions.
If you can't find any errors here then I'll be coming back with more later. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I wouldn't recommend naming a class `Object`.  It might cause more confusion than you're expecting

Comment: Nothing wrong with what you're doing, probably your header / source setup is wrong. Please show more of Object.h, Food.h and Snake.cpp. Do you use include guards?

Comment: No, it means you have to stop the handwaving and show some **real** code. Reduce what you have to the smallest example that you can create that still shows the problem.

Comment: Using `Object **blocks;` for an array seems wrong.

Comment: OT: Is it your intent that `Object` be inherited privately? Seeing the  actual `Object` declaration would probably speak volumes.

Comment: NuclearGhost: I don't have better fantasy than this, sorry.
Kos and Pete: I will add more afterhand. Thanks for yor comments
Mustafa: **blocks is i pointer to an array of pointers. These pointers  point to Object objects (sorry for the confusion).
WhozCraig: Thank you for noticing. I've fixed that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error. By some reason, probobly a test or misstake I had accidently included #include "Snake.h" inside Object.h as at the same time I had included #include "Object.h" inside Snake.h

Don't now why you can only include the one file inside another and not **also** the other way around but, I simply removed #include "Snake.h" from Object.h and it works now! The strangest thing and what I don't understand at all is why the #include "Food.h" for food.cpp triggered the error. If someone know this please reply, I want to learn by my misstakes.

Anyway, thanks to all who answered!